# How to set the context for webpack-hot-middleware

Tags: webpack

I have a repository containing two projects:

1) A typescript library
2) A standalone test application for that library. The test application puts the library in a web page for easier testing.

Each project has its own package.json, etc. My goal is for the standalone repo to use webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware. I'm struggling to make webpack-hot-middleware work properly.

If I install webpack-hot-middleware in both repositories, then everything works. If I install it only in the standalone repository then it fails to work. I had a similar issue getting webpack-dev-middleware working and had to set the context properly in webpack.config. From reading the documentation, it doesn't appear there is a way to set the context for webpack-hot-middleware. Does anyone know of a way? I can always install webpack-hot-middleware in both locations but would prefer to keep things cleaner.

Here is a standalone repo containing this problem:

https://github.com/bdsanfelippo/problem

To reproduce:

- clone the repo
- npm install
- cd standalone
- npm install
- npm start

Would appreciate any help!